# How to mock "require" in unit tests using Karma/Webpack/ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, webpack

I have this `ui-image` directive that I'm trying to unit-test. I'm using karma, webpack 2, and angular 1.4.14.

**Directive**

```
    function uiImage() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          const src = attr.uiImage || attr.src;

          // required for webpack to pick up image
          function loadImage(image) {
            return require(`images/${image}`);
          }

          element.attr('src', loadImage(src));
        }
      };
    }

    uiImage.$inject = [];

    export default uiImage;
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to unit-test this directive, since it's using the `require` statement. Is there any way to stub out or mock `require`?

Comment: I think testing that `loadImage` is called would suffice.

Comment: Do you use `karma-webpack` https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack as a pre-process tool for karma?

Comment: Yes I use `karma-webpack`.